# Weird output debugging the forward of an object with InverseTranformDirection

Tags: unity-game-engine, math, vector, inverse-transform

sorry for my bad english! I will try to explain the situation. Im just playing with this function because i want to understand how it works. The concept is really clear but debugging the forward of the object that i am debugging i get really weird output. For example im using InverTranformDirection(Vector3.Forward) to see what vector i get from the object child of another object. They are both perfectly aligned with their own axies. If i try rotate the parent of the object in order to have the forward pointing at (0,0,1) the child object that i am debugging has the same z axis value like it should have because they are alligned but if i rotate the parent to get the forward rotated on the (1,0,0) space cordinates, i get the cordinates inverted (-1,0,0). I mean why? Parent and child are pointing they own forward in the same exactly direction. Could you help me understand? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`InverseTranformDirection(Vector3.Forward)`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform.InverseTransformDirection.html)

wouldn't care about the parent at all. It is simply converting the **world space global Z axis** direction (= `(0, 0, 1)`) into local space of the according object.

I'd say it does exactly what you would expect.

Rotating your object to its own forward vector points towards `(1,0,0)` (=`Vector3.right` = world X axis) basically means the world space forward vector `(0, 0, 1)` (=`Vector3.forward`) is now pointing **left** away from your object.

Which is what `(-1, 0, 0)` would mean in its local space.

```
Vector3.forward (= -transform.right)
(world Z axis)     (local negative X axis)
^
|
|

rotated Object ----> Vector3.right (= transform.forward)
                     (world X axis)   (local Z axis)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot DerHugo! I perfectly got it!! I think i just misunderstood how it worked from the beginning. Many many thanks!!!